# how to find that the client is reading from tcp buffer in go

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

I'm starting to use golang for a quite amount of time for a project. In my project I have to implement a tcp server which responds to tcp clients. The server has to send a number of messages to a client.
The problem is that when a server writes a message to a client connection,  it has to wait until the client has read that message from buffer and then send another message (the server has to wait until the client calls the `reader.ReadString('\n')` method).

In my server code I wrote:

```
for {
    data := <-client.outgoing
    client.writer.WriteString(data + "\n")
    client.writer.Flush()
}
```

but the server sends all the messages to client without waiting for ReadString in client.

How to make server wait until the client read a message and then send the other message?

Comment: You can't. That's not how TCP works.

Comment: is there any way to get the client tcp free buffer size??

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Can you step back and explain what you're trying to achieve (i.e. the higher-level view)?

Comment: the question is part of my school project. Maybe I got the point wrong but I read the project and I thought that this is what I have to do. I have to read the project again then

Comment: If you go down to a low enough level in the TCP stack, you can get a pessimistic view of what's left in the remote receive window, basically how long until your sends start blocking. This still wouldn't tell you _when_ the client actually reads a message. The TCP stack can't even know what it means for your application to "read" it anyway; has it been received at the right application layer? Has it been successfully processed by the client? There's a reason this is done at the application layer.

Comment: If this is part of a school project, then you're certainly making things too complicated. No sane school would expect you to do this. (If your school is actually requiring this, you should sue for the cost of your tuition and time lost, because they're clearly unqualified to be teaching this stuff... :P)

Answer (score 1):

I think that either the assignment is ambiguous or you're misinterpreting it and solving [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The short answer is that **you can never know whether the client has read a message just by looking at the TCP conversation**. You have to implement this "protocol" in your application.

Here are a few problems:

1. From your application you don't *really* have access to what TCP is doing. You get a stream on which you can perform I/O.

   - The fact that a write to your stream "succeeds" only means that TCP has agreed to try to transport your stuff and has an independent copy. It doesn't say anything about whether the data has been received and it doesn't even mean the data has been even sent
   - You may find certain mechanisms to peer into TCP's inner workings (such as `ioctl`s, `SIOCINQ`, `SIOCOUTQ` or various setsockopts): these won't help
2. Even if you find out what your TCP is doing, this only tells you **what the remote TCP is doing**. So if you have full control over your TCP and even see the acknowledgments from the peer, you still don't know **what the application is doing**. It's very possible the application didn't read the data yet (it might not have requested the data, the TCP might be withholding it in a buffer for some weird reason, the scheduler might not have scheduled the remote process etc.)

Going back to your question, a way to really know whether the remote application has received your message is to have the remote application tell you. This means you have to restructure your protocol to:

1. Send stuff from the server
2. Wait for a message from the application telling you it received your stuff
3. Send more stuff (because you know from point 2 it's safe to do so)